How to run Odoo mobile framework in Android version 11 emulator?
I want to compile Odoo Mobile Framework android app on android version 11 emulator. I use Odoo erp version 10.0, I called product list mobile function from odoo erp ver10.0 then mobile app can insert datas(product list)in sqlite. But not show product list in screen of Product at mobile app. Also this function normal work on  android version 10 emulator.  Why? How to fix?
Tell me about difference of Android version 10 vs Android version 11 with Odoo ERP mobile framework.
